# In view how to return Razor int value for checkbox or click

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I do scaffolding and i have this in my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Plano, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Plano, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Plano, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
</div>
```

But i want return in checkbox or onclick a int value to my model.Plano, it's possible ?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.
model.Plano is a int property and you need the checkbox to send an integer value on post?

Comment: Sorry, yes model.Plano is a int property of one model. I need to understand how to send int value using checkbox or using click in text (choice1 choice2 choice3 return different value to model.Plano)

Comment: `Checkbox` has two state : checked and unchecked . So this Implies that value should be of bool type . Isn't it better to use another control rather than checkbox ?

Comment: Maybe a multiselect list. And after receive the values on post, you can set a one int value to your Plano property based in your logic (bit mask, etc...) to define this int value according to the options.

Comment: Okey, i'm testing and i will return this method. Obrigado // Thank's